# Ruby on Rail s: Getting NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## ERROR

```
Failure/Error: click_link "New Todo Item"   
 NoMethodError:   
 undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass 
 # ./app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb:25:in `todo_item_params' 
 # ./app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb:13:in `new'    
 # ./spec/features/todo_items/create_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top
(required)>'
```

## my create_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Adding todo items" do
  let!(:todo_list) { TodoList.create(title: "Grocery list", description: "Groceries") }

  def visit_todo_list(list)
    visit "/todo_lists"
    within "#todo_list_#{list.id}" do
      click_link "List Items"
    end
  end

  it "is successful with valid content" do
    visit_todo_list(todo_list)
    click_link "New Todo Item"
    fill_in "Content", with: "Milk"
    click_button "Save"
    expect(page).to have_content("Added todo list item.")
    within("ul.todo_items") do
      expect(page).to have_content("Milk")
    end
  end

end
```

## my todo_items_controller.rb

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
  end

  def new
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new
  end   

  def new
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new(todo_item_params)
    if @todo_item.save
        flash[:success] = "Added todo list item."
        redirect_to todo_list_todo_item_path
    else
        flash[:error] = "There was a problem adding that todo list item."
        render action: :new 
    end 
  end

  private 
  def todo_item_params
    params[:todo_item].permit(:content)
  end   
end
```

Comment: check params[:todo_item] it is `nil`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: cant get rid of the error

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `todo_item_params` to:

```
private 
def todo_item_params
  params.require(:todo_item).permit(:content)
end
```

Comment: #tried but still getting error                                                                   Failure/Error: click_link "New Todo Item"
ActionController::ParameterMissing:
param is missing or the value is empty: todo_item
# ./app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb:25:in `todo_item_params'
# ./app/controllers/todo_items_controller.rb:13:in `new'
# ./spec/features/todo_items/create_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: @RohitYadav How is your form look like? Can you post the params that are generated in the logs while submitting the form in the question?

Comment: <%= form_for [@todo_list, @todo_item] do |form| %>
 <%= form.lable :content %>
 <%= form.text_field :content %>
 
 <%= form.submit "Save" %>
<% end %>

Comment: @RohitYadav Please edit your question with the form code and the params that are generated in the logs

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two reasons for this error:

The first  is in your `todo_item_params` method. You have to change this as suggested by pavan like:

```
def todo_item_params
  params.require(:todo_item).permit(:content)
end
```

The second issue is you have two `new` methods in your controller. There is no `create`, `save` and `update` method.